# Why doesnt concatenation add a space in a url?

Tags: php

I am wondering why concatenation will echo a space in a text line, but when I add it to a URL it does not add a space? If I didnt add the space between each concatenation would this URL still work?

```
<?php foreach($products as $id => $p) { ?>
    <div class="container">          
    <?php 
     echo '<a href="test.php?id=' . $id . '">';
     echo '<img src="' . $p['img'] . '">'; 
    ?> 
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Concatenation does not add spaces out of the blue. If you put it there or the concatenated variable is not trimmed, it will be there... otherwise, not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
echo '<a href="test.php?id=' . $id . '">';
```

is the same thing than

```
echo '<a href="test.php?id='.$id.'">';
```

The space before and after the concatenation operator (the dot) is just to make it more readable

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look like this:

```
<?php foreach($products as $id => $p) { ?>
    <div class="container">          
    <?php 
        echo '<a href="test.php?id=', htmlentities($id), '">',
            '<img src="', htmlentities($p['img']), '">',
            '</a>', PHP_EOL;
    ?> 
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

- `echo` does not require a `.` to concat. It can use `,` as it's a language construct and has special treatment. You are doing a pointless concat on output when you can just output.
- You should escape attributes with `htmlentities` to stay safe.
- You should close the `</a>` after the `<img>`.
- This `'x'.'y'` is the same as `'x' . 'y'`. The space is discarded by PHP but it's used by devs for readability.